# Can manifolds be uniformly approximated by varieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, manifolds

Can manifolds be uniformly approximated by varieties in the way that continuous functions can be uniformly approximated by polynomials?

I got the idea from reading the Princeton companion to mathematics when it gave:

> **Theorem (Nash)** Let $M$ be a manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Fix any large number $R$. Then there is a polynomial $f$ whose zero set is as close to $M$ as we want, at least inside a ball of radius $R$ around the origin.

Comment: What do you mean by "in the way that..." ?  Given a manifold what would you like an approximation to it to mean?

Comment: My idea is very fuzzy. I don't know in what way or what type of approximation.

Comment: Do you only care about smooth manifolds or are $C^k$-manifolds also fine?