# Can any smooth manifold be realized as the zero set of some polynomials?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-topology, manifolds

Is any real smooth manifold diffeomorphic to a real affine algebraic variety? (I.e. is there an "algebraic" Whitney embedding theorem?)

And are all possible ways of realizing a manifold $M$ as an algebraic variety equivalent? I.e. suppose $M$ is diffeomorphic to varieties $V_1$ and $V_2$, are these isomorphic in the algebraic category?

Admittely I'm just asking out of curiosity after reading this question: [Can manifolds be uniformly approximated by varieties?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25082)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A quick Google search found [this paper](http://math.usask.ca/~fischer/preprint/defalgebraic1.pdf), where it is stated that the answer to the first question is yes in the compact case (due to Tognoli): this result is called the Nash-Tognoli theorem. In general, the answer is no: a real affine variety has finite-rank homology groups, and it's easy to construct non-compact manifolds for which this is false (e.g. a surface of infinite genus). In fact, apparently there is a bound [due to Milnor](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~shmuel/QuantCourse%20/Milnor,%20betti%20numbers%20of%20real%20varieties.pdf) for the sum of the Betti numbers of a real variety.

The answer to the second question is certainly not: just take two elliptic curves with slightly different $j$-invariants.

Comment: Sorry, what's the paper you link to in the first paragraph? I can't access it... Somehow this made me think of [Claire Voisin's recent results](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~voisin/Articlesweb/template.pdf): e.g. there are compact Kähler manifolds that don't have the homotopy type of a complex projective manifold (see Q.3.15 and Thm 3.16 on p. 17). This is not strictly related, but still... probably worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks! Your first link leads me to a "file not available", but after typing in my question into google (what I should have done in the first place) I get http://www.springerlink.com/content/j53406713j831452/ which cites Tognoli for the statement about closed manifolds.

Comment: The original link wasn't freely available, so I replaced it with a different paper.

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of completeness, here is the answer  covering noncompact manifolds as well:

**Definition.** 1. A smooth manifold $M$ is **tame** if $M$ is diffeomorphic to the interior of a smooth compact manifold $N$ with (possibly empty) boundary.

2. A smooth manifold $M$ is **algebraic** if it is diffeomorphic to a
   nonsingular real-algebraic subset of ${\mathbb R}^n$ for some $n$.

**Theorem.** A smooth manifold is tame if and only if it is algebraic.

See Corollary 4.3 in

*Akbulut, Selman; King, Henry C.*, [**The topology of real algebraic sets with isolated singularities**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2006992), Ann. Math. (2) 113, 425-446 (1981). [ZBL0494.57004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0494.57004).